# Can join with Cassandra table get pushdown?

Tags: apache-spark, join, cassandra, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using structured stream. I need to left join a huge (billions of rows) Cassandra table to know whether the source data in micro-batch is new or existed in terms of id col. If I do something like:

```
val src = spark.read.cassandraFormat("src", "ks").load().select("id")
val query= some_dataset
      .join(src, expr("src.id=some_dataset.id"), joinType = "leftOuter")
      .withColumn("flag", expr("case when src.id is null then 0 else 1 end"))
      .writeStream
      .outputMode("update")
      .foreach(...)
      .start
```

Can Cassandra push down the left join and look up with the join col value in source delta? Is there a way to tell whether the pushdown happened or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not in the open source version of Spark Cassandra Connector. There is a support for it as [DSE Direct Join in DSE Analytics](http://www.russellspitzer.com/2018/05/23/DSEDirectJoin/), so if you use DataStax Enterprise, you'll get it. If you're using OSS connector [you're limited to RDD API only](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#performing-efficient-joins-with-cassandra-tables-since-12).

Update, May 2020th: optimized join on dataframes is supported since SCC 2.5.0, together with other commercial features.  See this [blog posts](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all) for details.